# Send to Google Plus from Reader

Tags: google-reader, google-plus, google-chrome-extensions

Is it **currently** possible to send to Google Plus from Google Reader?

Either a Chrome extension or a custom Send To link would work.

**Update**: This question is now obsolete. With the changes to Reader, Google+ sharing is now integrated.

Comment: Send as in things you like/share showing up in Google+?

Comment: @EightDaysofMalaise: kinda. Have you used the Send To functionality of Reader? It sends the title and the link (already shortened) so I can edit and post. In G+, I'd be able to choose circles, etc.

Comment: It is ridiculous that this isn't doable by default!

Comment: I suggest removing the "Update: Now obsolete..." because the current integration (as of 11/7/2011) only allows you to +1 a post which shows it in your Profile->+1 tab. I don't know if that is very useful if it doesn't put it in your feed or let you comment, or set the sharing (with your circles) options.

Comment: @Mufasa, the `Share...` button on the top bar is working for me...

Comment: @DiegoMijelshon: They removed the old Share under the post (where the +1 is now). I did not realize that the new Google+ share button at the _top_ of the Reader site is aware of which post in the list you were actively viewing. Apparently it does. That will work then. Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As far as I know it is not possible to share articles in Google Reader to Google Plus.

Google Reader expects a custom Send To link in the format of a URL where as Google Plus functionality requires Javascript to post/share items.

**EDIT**

The only alternative I can suggest is [this Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ppjihganhojelngokopdocghcngoapfd?hl=en) which adds the Google+1 button to your toolbar. This enables you to +1 the current site that you are visiting.  Although it doesn't directly enable you to share Google Reader posts - you can open the link directly in your browser and then click the +1 button.

You should remember that this adds the current site to your +1 tab it does NOT post this to your stream.

Comment: That's fine. Any extensions or -at worst- bookmarklets then?

Comment: @DiegoMijelshon: Not that I am aware of no. I would think many more tools will be available once the API has been opened up to Developers.

Comment: the +1 solution won't do because I'm specifically interested in posting to the stream.

Comment: you'll have to wait till Google opens G+ API @DiegoMijelshon

Comment: @Sathya: ...or provides their own Send To G+ :-)   Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I found the perfect Chrome Extension - adds "Share on Google Plus" in Reader. Here's the link.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cngpndgifehgejmkemnmmiknpafnhpec

Works a charm for me.

Answer (score 3):

You can drag the link from the item in Google Reader to the share button On the Google bar. It will start a new message for you with the link inserted. You can then add more to the message and select circles before sending.

Comment: Interesting. But drag-n-drop is **so** not my thing...

Comment: Cutting and pasting the link also works. Hopefully there will be better integration between Reader and G+ in the future, but right now I believe we're stuck with the status bar.

Comment: I know cut and paste works, but that's exactly what I'm trying to avoid :-)

Answer (score 3):

While we're waiting for a native way to do this, someone found the URLs to use to make a customized "Send to" solution.

Source: [ReadWriteWeb](http://www.readwriteweb.com/archives/how_to_share_google_reader_stories_to_google_plus.php)

1. Go to Google Reader, click the gear icon, and choose 'Reader settings'
2. Click the 'Send To' tab
3. Scroll down all the way and click 'Create a custom link'
4. Enter the following into the fields that appear:

   - Name: `Google+`
   - URL: `https://plusone.google.com/_/+1/confirm?hl=en&url=${url}`
   - Icon URL: `https://ssl.gstatic.com/s2/oz/images/favicon.ico`
5. Click 'Save,' and Google+ will appear checked, with the nice icon next to it:

After this, when you're reading any article in Google Reader  you'll see Google+ in the 'Send to' drop-down menu at the bottom. (You will probably have to refresh the browser page after you do this.)

Comment: If you read that article, it actually references http://www.howtonew.com/how-to-post-from-google-reader-to-google as the source. I also found it at http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/reader/thread?tid=3dcfd935bfb48935&hl=en but I don't know which came first.

Comment: It's all moot now anyway, since Reader has been fairly deeply integrated with G+.

Answer (score 2):

With the recent changes to Google Reader, [this is now possible](http://www.google.com/support/reader/bin/answer.py?answer=83000). You can either click the **+1** button at the bottom of an item and optionally add a comment, or you can click in the **Share...** field at the top right corner of the window. The **Share...** field lets you share without adding the item to your +1 list.

[image: +1 on Google Reader]

Comment: Indeed. This question is now obsolete.

Comment: The "Share" option has been removed from Google Reader. Now you can only use the +1 button in Reader, which does not (as of 11/7/2011) post it in your feed or let you comment or share it. It only puts it in your Profile->+1 tab list. And who looks at that regularly?

Comment: Are you sure your account has been switched to the new look, @Mufasa? If so, carefully read the [Google help page](http://www.google.com/support/reader/bin/answer.py?answer=83000) I linked to. There are two steps: first, click +1 and second, add a note. You can skip the +1 step if you use the **Share...** option. That is now in the top right corner of the window.

Comment: @DonKirkby: Oh, I did not realize you have to add a comment in that box for it to turn it into a full Post. Not the best interface since it does two different things based on the existence or absence of a comment without any description that it does that, but it will work. Thanks!