# How can I share posts from GoogleReader to Google+

Tags: google-plus, google-reader, rss-reader

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Send to Google Plus from Reader](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/17044/send-to-google-plus-from-reader)

How can I add Google+ to the custom "Share" items in GoogleReader?

According to [this question and lack of resolution,](https://www.google.com/support/forum/p/reader/thread?tid=3696ba39aaccb42f&hl=en) it is not possible?

David Vielmetter suggests that [dragging-and-dropp](http://davidvielmetter.com/tricks/share-google-reader-items-on-google-plus/) to the "share" bar at the top of the screen is the only way to do it.

[PlusFeed](http://freenuts.com/read-google-in-google-reader-with-plusfeed/) allows you to read Google+ in GoogleReader -- just not the other way around. aaargh!

C'mon lazy-web, where's the solution?!?

Answer (score 3):

There's no solution till Google releases an API that developers can utilize